# AJAX not calling PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a contact us form and I'm trying to send the form data to an email address via AJAX and PHP. The submit function is being fired successfully and I receive the `alert("success!");`. However it seems the `form-process.php` file is never executed - I never receive the `echo "I have got this far";` and I certainly don't receive an email. Where am I going wrong?

For info I have a staging site setup so the files are already hosted on the server.

#### HTML

```
<div class="modal" id="contactModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Us</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="form-process.php" method="POST" id="contact-form" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control my-2" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
            <input type="email" class="form-control my-2" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control my-2" name="message" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here..."></textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="contact-form"></input>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
    console.log('this has fired');

    var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[id=name]').val(),
        'email'             : $('input[id=email]').val(),
        'message'           : $('input[id=message]').val()
    };

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form-process.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#contact-modal").modal('hide');
            alert("success!");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("form post failed");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
$myemail = '<myemailaddress>';
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $company = strip_tags($_POST['company']);

    echo "I have got this far";

    $to = $myemail;
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
        " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
        "Email: $email\n Company \n $company";
    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: ___seems like `form-process.php` is not run___ Did you check the apache access log to see if it ever was run?

Comment: `<div class="modal" id="contactModal">` < is that the ID for `$("#contact-modal").modal('hide');`? I didn't see an ID matching `contact-modal`.

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: That's because your inputs don't have ids. Vote to close as typo

Comment: Thanks all, silly typo on my end - Jay's answer fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the following to get the values of the input fields:

```
$('input[id=name]').val(),
$('input[id=email]').val(),
$('input[id=message]').val()
```

But none of your inputs has an `id` field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control my-2" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
<input type="email" class="form-control my-2" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
<textarea type="text" class="form-control my-2" name="message" rows="4" name="message" placeholder="Write your message here..."></textarea>
      </div>
```

So you can use this to get those values:

```
$(input[name="name"]).val();
$(input[name="email"]).val();
$(input[name="message"]).val();
```

Comment: Doh! This fixed it, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All three of your `formData` subobjects are empty - those three input selectors with ids simply don't exist, so `isset($_POST['name'])` is always false.